# I can't view my phone on azure vm

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v, azure

I have a problem with my azure VM, I would like to share my phone to perform automated mobile tests with Cerberus.

So I did some research and here is what I did.

- I allowed local resource sharing when connecting RDP
  [Screen RDP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMACM.png)
- I enabled the Hyper-V enhanced session on the VM 
  [First screen Hyper-V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFwtp.png)
  [Second screen Hyper-V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PxBG.png)
- I restart the VM

By reconnecting, I can see my hard drive but not my phone.
[Screen file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCOUI.png)

Do you have a solution ?
Where can the problem come from ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible due to the software installed on the phone. You can share items like USB however.

I would suggest you check if this is the case by sharing a resource such as a Mic or USB to the VM and if it works then you do have it configured correctly however there would be an issue with the phone device you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;) I continued my search by trying to install necessary drivers, but Microsoft support told me that Azure VMs were currently incompatible.